# Regex in Word documents

Tags: python, regex, ms-word

I have a large text document with inconsistent quotation marks, i.e.

```
...Dolore magna aliquam “lorem ipsum” dolor sit amet, 'consectetuer adipiscing" elit, volutpat. Ut "wisi" enim...
```

and I want to convert every style of quotation marks to Guillemet style (» and «), so that example sentence should be like

```
...Dolore magna aliquam »lorem ipsum« dolor sit amet, »consectetuer adipiscing« elit, volutpat. Ut »wisi« enim...
```

I was thinking about regular expression like

```
`` ["'”“](.*?)["'”“]``
```

but I only know how to write code in Python. 
Is there a way to accomplish that in Python? If not, could someone provide a tip on how to accomplish that directly in MS Word. I tried with find/replace and wildcards, but that inconsistency in using quotation mark bugs me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this pattern:

```
([“'"](?=[a-zA-Z\,\.\s])([a-zA-Z\,\.\s]*)[”'"])
```

Replacement:

```
»$2«
```

**EDIT**: Since you've mentioned **Python** I've come up with something that should definitely work:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# coding: utf-8
import os, sys
import re
import codecs

with codecs.open('/path/to/file.txt', 'r', 'utf-8') as f:
    encoded = f.read()
    encoded = encoded.replace( u'\u201c', u'\"')
    encoded = encoded.replace( u'\u201d', u'\"')
    encoded = encoded.encode('utf-8')
    result = re.sub('(\s[\“\'\"](?=[a-zA-Z\,\.\s]*)([a-zA-Z\,\.\s]*)[\”\'\"]\s)', ' »\\2« ', encoded)
    decoded_result = result.decode('utf-8')
    print format(decoded_result)
```

Replace the `/path/to/file.txt` with the location of your file (saved with utf-8 encoding).

*The code above does a couple things differently than a standard search and replace because of the character encodings used in punctuation. There might be a cleaner way of getting the same end result, although the entire encoding thing is tricky with Python, so it's anyone's guess.*

Comment: If you have accented words then: `([\s“'"](?=[a-zA-Z\,\.\s])([a-zA-Z\,\.\s]+)[”'"]\s)` should be used.

Comment: Thanks! Altough that pattern doesn't return anything in my Word 2007, but probably I'm doing something wrong. I'm going to check that once more.

Comment: Try the Python code I've added to the answer and let me know how it works.

Comment: It's working great! The only problem occurs when a word inside a question mark ends right before a comma or a full stop. I.e. `This "works" and this "does not", neither does 'this'.` would result as `This »works« and this "does not", neither does 'this'.`

Comment: Try using this: `result = re.sub('(\s[\“\'\"](?=[a-zA-Z\,\.\s]*)([a-zA-Z\,\.\s]*)[\”\'\"])', ' »\\2«', encoded)`. I took out the last `\s` and removed the space from the end of the `' »\\2«' ` replacement.

Answer (score 1):

Ms Word can directly use regular expressions if you check the right option in "Find" window (something like "special characters"), so you simply have to perform a find/replace in Ms Word. Replace:

```
[“”'"»«]
```

with

```
'
```

Above is an example if you want to use only the `'` character as quotation mark.
This will (for example) replace:

```
»consectetuer adipiscing"
```

with:

```
'consectetuer adipiscing'
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply! But, that works only if I want to replace to apostrophe (') quotation. Other way around, replacing other quot marks with »« would result with some downsides. I.e, 'this example' would result with probably »this example», instead of »this example«.

Comment: So if I understand your need, you don't want `"foo»` to be replaced with `'foo'`? The two surrounding quotation marks shall be homogeneous to be replaced?

Comment: Well, the goal is to change every quotation mark to same one, `»«`, i.e. `»this«` instead of 'this', 'this", "this" etc.

Comment: OK. So I guess it must be something like `[\'\"”“](<*>)[\'\"”“]` or `['"”“](<*>)['"”“]` to be replaced in Ms Word with `»\1«`. But this doesn't seem to work for `'` and `"`. Don't know why...